# sklearn NMF, the inference weight values are changed whenever I try it again

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nmf

Whenever I'm doing inference (nmf_model.transform(matrix))
The weight value of each topics for documents are changed.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

nmf_model = NMF(
  n_components = 7,
  init = 'nndsvda',
  solver = 'mu',
  beta_loss = 'Frobenius',
  max_iter = 500,
  tol = 0.000001, 
  alpha = 0.1,
  l1_ratio = 0,
  shuffle = True
)
```

I'm doing Topic modeling using NMF.

I saved this model and doing an inference.
But I tried it twice, the result was changed.

For example,

```
version 1 : 
topic_001 : weight 0.013663
topic_002 : weight 0.072554
topic_003 : weight 0.000056
```

....

but version 2 doesn't have same weight value with version 1, even I didn't change anything when I'm doing an inference.

Below is my Inference code

```
data_mat = csc_matrix.transpose(gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(ref_corpus + corpus))[len(ref_corpus):]

nmf_model.transform(data_mat)
```

Does anyone knows why its happend?
I want to fix it so that I can get same values whenever I try it again.

Comment: please provide a concise, reproducible (runnable) example of your issue

Comment: I edit my question! Thanks

Comment: Ah oops, I misunderstood. So after you create `nmf_model`, what code are you using to infer with `nmf_model`?

Comment: I'm doing "nmf_model.transform(data_mat)" 

`data_mat = csc_matrix.transpose(gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(ref_corpus + corpus))[len(ref_corpus):]`

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments, edit & update your question instead.

Comment: It's first time to upload question.. Thanks for advice, I edit and update my question:)

Comment: hi @Grace.K, this is better, but still not runnable without data.   You can either provide a sample of data in your question (with e.g. df.to_dict()) or some other code that generates the exact data you are using (e.g. sklearn.datasets).

Comment: it is otherwise very difficult to provide a correct answer